Does updating the source of an image multiple times per second lead to performance issues?
I'm not really sure how to wrap this question in a single sentence, but I'll explain in as few words as I can.
The landing page for my (work in progress) website is a picture of a building, and you can click on the door to get to a different page. Before the location changes, the source of an image in the page changes every 33 ms in order to simulate a 30fps animation.
This is in my .blade.php file (I'm using Laravel 11):
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" id="landingSvg">
            <image width="1920" height="1080" xlink:href="/media/frames/1.jpg" id="landingImage"></image>
                <rect x="599" y="678" fill="#fff" opacity="0" width="136" height="261" id="door"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div>

While this is the Javascript that handles the animation (I'm using jQuery):
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#door").click(() => {
        //Hiding the door element
        $("#door").hide();
        //Initializing frame count as 2
        let i = 2;
        //Using an interval to change the image url every 33 milliseconds, simulating a 30fps animation
        let frames = setInterval(() => {
            //Changing the image url of the main background to the next frame
            $("#landingImage").attr("xlink:href", `/media/frames/${i}.jpg`);
            //Increasing the frame count
            i++;
            //Checking if the counter has reached the value of 31, as in that case there will be no more frames to load
            if (i >= 31) {
                clearInterval(frames);
                //Changing position to the next page after 700 milliseconds
                setTimeout(() => {
                    window.location.assign('http://localhost:8000/reception');
                }, 700)
            }
        }, 33)
    }
)
// $(document).ready() ends here
})

I tested this on my local machine and it works fine. I rarely get some frame skipping, but almost always the animation is very smooth.
Now, this is what I was wondering: when I eventually ship the application to production, playing the animation means requesting a fairly large image (1920x1080) every 33 ms from a server that is possibly fairly distant from the user; will the server be able to perform this operation as smoothly? If not, what can I do to solve the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Chances are it won't work like you want. You should probably just use a video instead of emulating a video with loose frames, or if for some reason you can't use a video, use a single "spritesheet" style image you show parts of.

", playing the animation means requesting a fairly large image (1920x1080) every 33 ms from a server that is possibly fairly distant from the user; will the server be able to perform this operation as smoothly?" this would depend on the network connection which the server does not control. If the user is using pigeons to carry the internet packets they would have high latency for each packet. Not doable within 33ms. Unless it's a cached. Which is a good consideration - why not request the images immediately rather than each frame?

It sounds like you went really far down the rabbit hole on a solution that's a "square peg in a round hole". In other words, this solution has a lot of overhead in performance and development, compared to existing solutions that utilize video or streaming methods.

Yes, it will lead to performance issues depending on the internet connection of the server/client. Slower connections could have trouble to process the images in time before the next request is made. When you use the images stored on your own computer, such as with "localhost", the requested images are already available on your machine without having to pull them from a server via internet connection.
Maybe use animations as one whole file that aren't huge data chunks (Such as a .gif). 1920x1080 is quite a size for fast .jpg requests. The smaller the file, the better the performance should be.
If you really want to use the solutions with .jpg files, you could request them before you use them and store them locally. When you got the images, you could switch them with the "setInterval" out. Depending on the size of your project, this could be more memory intensive, but it should allow you to deal with the clients performance issues.
EDIT: As explained by @AKX, using Videos should be a better solution. I didn't knew the difference in size between GIFs and videos before.

1920x1080 would be a huge .gif too.

@AKX Yeah... So maybe caching/storing is the best solution. Or sizing the images down and scaling them clientside. I think the question then would be image quality vs performance.

As I mentioned in the comments, the best solution would be a video file. :)
